# How to group by in FOR XML clause in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2014, for-xml-path

I have this schema in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f66c/7)

[image]

My code:

```
SELECT  
    MUID, weekcounter,
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' + Category
           FROM tb EE
           WHERE EE.MUID = E.MUID AND Ranknum <= 3
           FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') AS listStr
FROM tb E
GROUP BY E.MUID, E.weekcounter
```

I am getting wrong output like this:

[image]

I am expecting this output :

[image]

I don't have option to use `string_aggr()` in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you want to get the desired output, you'd have to use the two columns you want to group by in the correlated subquery (in the `STUFF` part), too.

Try this code:

```
SELECT  
    MUID, weekcounter,
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' + Category
           FROM tb EE
           WHERE EE.MUID = E.MUID 
             AND EE.weekcounter = E.weekcounter
             AND Ranknum <= 3
           FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') AS listStr
FROM 
    tb E
GROUP BY 
    E.MUID, E.weekcounter
```

Comment: Opps I forgot that simple part to add  "AND EE.weekcounter = E.weekcounter" Thanks buddy!!